# Access preview settings in php

Tags: php, theme-customizer, get-theme-mod

I'm working with the customize section of my theme framework.
And I'm trying to get the preview settings in PHP when using refresh, but I only know how to access the saved settings.

---

**Short Story**

I want to get the value like this:

```
if (is_customize_preview()) {
    $outputUrl = get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/styleTemp.css';
    $color1 = //How do I get the preview value??
} else {
    $outputUrl = get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css';   
    $color1 = get_theme_mod('rhyme_color_1', '#000');
}
//Does less compilation to $outputUrl Css file

wp_enqueue_style('main-style', $outputUrl);
```

---

**Long Story**

The reason I am doing it with refresh is so that I can connect the theme_mods to less variables, that I compile on the server. I am then serving the compiled css to the site.

**I'm creating the setting**

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'rhyme_color_1',
    array(
        'default'     => '#000000',
        'transport'   => 'refresh',
        'type' => 'theme_mod',
        'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color'
    )
);
```

**Creating the control**

```
    $wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'color_1',
        array(
            'label'      => __( 'Color 1', 'rhyme' ),
            'section'    => 'colors',
            'settings'   => 'rhyme_color_1'
        )
    )
);
```

**Getting settings**

```
$color1 = get_theme_mod('rhyme_color_1', '#000');
```

When I use the get_theme_mod, I only get the saved value not the preview one. So when the user edits a value, he does not see any changes until he saves and updates the page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was that I was adding the function to 'init' and where the preview was not updated. Adding it to wp_enqueue_script solved my issue.

Changed

```
add_action('init', 'autoCompileLess');
```

to

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'autoCompileLess');
```